# Difference between starting a stopped container and creating a new one

Tags: docker, container

I am new to docker and wondering about what the difference is between:

- Running a previously stopped Docker container
- Creating and running a container from the same image as you would a stopped container

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34783353/5007273) SO answer that is related to my question but I'm afraid I don't quite understand it. What is a container layer? Is there any reason to create a new container for an image if you already have a stopped container made from that image (assuming I don't need persistence of the container's filesystem)?

Comment: Container layer: [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/#:~:text=When%20you%20create%20a%20new,this%20thin%20writable%20container%20layer.) Hopefully that helps you to understand:)

Comment: About your second question I would say that is according to your needs. For example, you can have an Ubuntu image and run a container from this one to install some CLI applications. Also you can have another container from the same image but for installing GUI applications. Note that when you want to run GUI applications you have to specify the next volume `/tmp/.X11-unix` like this: `docker run -ti  -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix --name "container_name" docker_image`

Comment: A volume is a way *to share or mount* a [file](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/1224462) from the host (your main operating system) to your container. So if you don't run an image with `-v` then once you created the container this cannot be modified to specify some volume.